# CSS vertical text needs to much space

Tags: html, css, vertical-text

I'm using CSS to create vertical text. The Problem is, I want to have the text next to the previous div and no space between or after. How can I fix this this?

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="pull-left">
      here is some stuff
  </div>
  <div class="pull-left verticalText changeCursor">I'm vertical</div>
</div>
```

CSS (pull-left from Bootstrap):

```
.changeCursor
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.verticalText
{
    height: 100%;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);  /* f&uuml;r Safari und Co */
    -o-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Opera */
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* MS IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "next to"? A picture of what you want would be very helpful.

Comment: here a picture
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3786/4ylg97i9_jpg.htm

the red one is div1, white area is the text-div, black would be next div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a `<div>` will, by default, be as wide as it can be.  Additionally, when you do the transform, the origin is by default in the middle of the element.

If you make them `display: inline-block` and add

```
transform-origin: 0 0;
```

to the `.vertical-text` rule, then the text ends up to the right of the first one, but it overlaps it. To fix *that*, you can use `translate()`:

```
#wrapper > div { display: inline-block; }

.verticalText
{
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0, -100%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0, -100%);  /* f&uuml;r Safari und Co */
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0, -100%); /* Opera */
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0, -100%); /* MS IE 9 */
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0, -100%);
}
```

[Here is a CodePen.](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/pHlct)